# streamlining series of try-except + if-statements for faster processing in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, iterator, try-except

I'm processing strings using regexes in a bunch of files in a directory. To each line in a file, I apply a series of try-statements to match a pattern and if they do, then I transform the input. After I have analyzed each line, I write it to a new file. I have *a lot* of these try-else followed by if-statements (I only included two here as an illustration). My issue here is that after processing a few files, the script slows down so much that it almost stalls the process completely. I don't know what in my code is causing the slowing down but I have a feeling it is the combination of try-else + if-statements. How can I streamline the transformations so that the data is processed at a reasonable speed?

Or is it that I need a more efficient iterator that does not tax memory to the same extent?

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

```
import re
import glob

fileCounter = 0 

for infile in glob.iglob(r'\input-files\*.txt'):

    fileCounter += 1
    outfile = r'\output-files\output_%s.txt' % fileCounter

    with open(infile, "rb") as inList, open(outfile, "wb") as outlist:

        for inline in inlist:

            inword = inline.strip('\r\n')

            #apply some text transformations
            #Transformation #1
            try: result = re.match('^[AEIOUYaeiouy]([bcćdfghjklłmnńprsśtwzżź]|rz|sz|cz|dz|dż|dź|ch)[aąeęioóuy](.*\[=\].*)*', inword).group()
            except: result = None

            if result == inword:
                inword = re.sub('(?<=^[AEIOUYaeiouy])(?=([bcćdfghjklłmnńprsśtwzżź]|rz|sz|cz|dz|dż|dź|ch)[aąeęioóuy])', '[=]', wbWord)

            #Transformation #2 etc.
            try: result = re.match('(.*\[=\].*)*(\w?\w?)[AEIOUYaąeęioóuy]\[=\][ćsśz][ptkbdg][aąeęioóuyrfw](.*\[=\].*)*', inword).group()
            except: result = None

            if result == inword:   
                inword =  re.sub('(?<=[AEIOUYaąeęioóuy])\[=\](?=[ćsśz][ptkbdg][aąeęioóuyrfw])', '', inword)
                inword =  re.sub('(?<=[AEIOUYaąeęioóuy][ćsśz])(?=[ptkbdg][aąeęioóuyrfw])', '[=]', inword)

            outline = inword + "\n"
            outlist.write(outline)

    print "Processed file number %s" % fileCounter          
print "*** Processing completed ***"
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try/except is indeed not the most efficient way (nor the most readable one) to test for the result of a `re.match()` , but the penalty hit should still be (more or less) constant - the performance should not degrade during execution (until perhaps there's some worst case happening due to your data but well) - so chances are the problem is elsewhere.

FWIW you can start by replacing your try/except blocks with the appropriate canonical solution, ie instead of:

```
try:
    result = re.match(someexp, yourline).group()
except:
    result = None
```

you want:

```
match = re.match(someexp, yourline)
result = match.group() if match else None
```

This will slightly improve perfs but, most importantly, make your code more readable and much more maintainable - at least it won't hide any **unexpected** error.

As a side note, **never** use a bare except clause, always only catch expected exceptions (here it would have been an `AttributeError` since `re.match()` returns `None` when nothing matched and `None` has of course no attribute `group`).

This will very probably NOT solve your problem but at least you'll then know the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Bruno. That's very helpful!